# sqlalchemy.orm.exc.FlushError: Instance has a NULL identity key. (ORACLE DB)

Tags: python, oracle, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, cx-oracle

I am having an issue with inserting data into a table in a flask app. I am getting the below error when committing to the db:

`sqlalchemy.orm.exc.FlushError: Instance <TestModel at 0x11120f690> has a NULL identity key.  If this is an auto-generated value, check that the database table allows generation of new primary key values, and that the mapped Column object is configured to expect these generated values.  Ensure also that this flush() is not occurring at an inappropriate time, such as within a load() event.`

I understand that Oracle uses sequences instead of Autoincrement and have specified that in my db.Model for the primary key:

```
class TestModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'TESTTABLE'
    id_seq = Sequence('TEST_SEQ')
    TESTID = db.Column(db.Integer, id_seq, primary_key=True)
```

I saw this exact error on Stackoverflow where it was fixed with a downgrade of cx_Oracle but I had no luck doing that. The Sequence is already created in the database. I am running python3.7, the latest version of cx_Oracle, and Oracle 18.1 DB.

Comment: "I understand that Oracle uses sequences instead of Autoincrement" >> as you're on 18.1, it offers **identity** columns (what you call "autoincrement") so - if you think it could help, switch to that instead of a sequence.